# Software рендеринг в QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Пытаюсь в своем кастомном QML компоненте (QQuickItem) нарисовать цветной квадрат.

QQuickItem::updatePaintNode:

```
QSGGeometryNode *rect = new QSGGeometryNode();
QSGFlatColorMaterial *material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial();
QSGGeometry *geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), 4);

QSGGeometry::updateRectGeometry(geometry, boundingRect());
material->setColor(QColor::fromString("red"));

rect->setMaterial(material);
rect->setGeometry(geometry);
```

Я использую software рендеринг:

```
QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface::Software);
```

И в таком виде ничего не рисуется - просто пустое место. Использую дефолтный Qt 6.6.0, выкаченный из MaintenanceTool на Linux.

Если поменять рендеринг, на что-то с GPU ускорением, например Vulkan, то квадрат успешно рисуется. Абсолютно точно так же рисование происходит под капотом в QSGSimpleRectNode (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsgsimplerectnode.html) и там таких проблем нет: при software рендеринге все рисуется успешно. **Я не хочу использовать QQuickPaintedItem, мне нужно починить software рендерениг в QQuickItem.** В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Как сделать универсальный QQuickItem, который бы при software рендеринге рисовался на CPU, а при наличии GPU рендеринга, соответственно на GPU?